# Show or Hide div to the left using Angular Animation

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-animations

I am showing mat-dialog with 600px height and width.

I have a button in mat-dialog. When I click on button, I want to show the left sliding div from the left side of mat-dialog without effecting mat-dialog.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: What do you want in stackblitz ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.

**Using angular Animations**

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azjfgh

Angular provides a sets of methods to do some cool stuff.
In this example I've wrote that:

```
animations: [
        trigger('widthGrow', [
            state('closed', style({
                width: 0,
            })),
            state('open', style({
                width: 400
            })),
            transition('* => *', animate(150))
        ]),
    ]
```

> **trigger** -> the name of the trigger we want to registrate and use in the html
>
> **state** -> two state that we will use in order to change our div.
>
> **style** -> the css property we want to change based on our logic.
>
> **transition** -> a simple timer that will animate the grow of the div.

If you open the stackblitz you will see how does it work.I used another div to trigger a function called *changeState* to change the property to animate it.

**Using just css**

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpjqnd

Using `transition` (native from css) and `ngClass` you can achieve the same thing.

Since it's just basic code I'm just putting here the css class:

```
.left-stuff {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: red;
}
```

If you need more help feel free to comment this answer.

Comment: I tried your first stackblitz and changed the width. For some reason it is behaving weird. Try 50 width and even replace 150 with 50 in animation and try

Comment: I tried with this settings: width = 50;

  changeState(): void { 
    (this.width === 50) ? this.width = 150 : this.width = 50;
  } and it's working fine. Have I missed something?